# The property 'MarkId' on entity type 'GameMarks' has a temporary value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Доброе время суток всем, прошу прощение чье время отнимаю.
Суть в том, что после того, как добавил метки в EF Core и проапдейтил базу, я не могу добавить в базу, из-за этой ошибки:

> InvalidOperationException: The property 'MarkId' on entity type
>   'GameMarks' has a temporary value

Как я могу пофиксить это?

```
public class Game
{  
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Ganre { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameMarks> GameMarks{ get; set; }
    public string PathGooglePlay { get; set; }
}

public class Marks
{
    [Key]
    public int MarkId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GameMarks> GameMarks { get; set; }
}

public class GameMarks
{
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Games { get; set; }
    public int MarkId { get; set; }
    public Marks Marks { get; set; }
}

public class GameContext : DbContext
{
    public GameContext(DbContextOptions<GameContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<GameMarks>()
    .HasKey(pc => new { pc.GameId, pc.MarkId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<GameMarks>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.Games)
            .WithMany(p => p.GameMarks)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.GameId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<GameMarks>()
            .HasOne(pc => pc.Marks)
            .WithMany(c => c.GameMarks)
            .HasForeignKey(pc => pc.MarkId);
    }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

public async Task PostGame([FromBody] Game game)
{
    game.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    _context.Games.Add(game);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Апгрейд базы был через миграцию? И покажите код как в базу добавляете новую запись о `GameMarks`

Comment: Да,через миграцию.

     @Bulson
    
     _context.Games.Add(Game);
       db.SaveChanges();
      _context.Marks.Addrange(Game.GameMarks.All(e=> e.Marks));
       db.SaveChanges();

Comment: `db.SaveChanges();` - это, извините, и ежу понятно. Вы покажите как у вас увязываются между собой `Game`, `GameMarks` и `Marks`   перед сохранением. Вы же должны делать примерно в след.порядке: 1)берете `Marks`, 2)создаете или извлекаете из БД  `GameMarks`, 3) добавляете в `Marks` эти `GameMarks`, 4)..., n) и потом уже сохраняете. Откорректируйте вопрос, добавьте этот код.